# LINQ To SQL Partial Class Inherits Only One Class Without Its Relationship

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, partial-classes

I have a few LINQ to SQL entity tables which have relationships from one to another.
Can anyone tell me a quick way to create a partial class that only inherits a class without its related entity included?

Answer (score 3):

> create a partial class that only inherits a class without its related entity

Well first of all when you declare a class as `partial` you aren't *inheriting* anything, you're *extending* the class. All `partial` does is allow you to build a class up across different files so essentially when you add properties/methods to it it's like adding it to the original declaration.

Secondly, it begs the question *why* you would want to ignore the related entity properties? They are automatically added as convenience methods so you can access data from related tables. If you don't want the relationship my advice would be to just remove it from the context at design time (bare in mind if you update your context from the database the relationships will be pulled down again).

Comment: Thanks for idea, re-generate new data context.

Comment: @sovantha actually see my updated answer, you don't even need to remove it from the database you can specifically remove it from the data context.